# Windows 7 wireless driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I can't find wireless driver (or any other drivers) for Acer TravelMate 4001WLMi.
OS is Windows 7.
There was Windows XP installed, but I've installed Windows 7. Now I'm unable to find any drivers for this model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does that model come with the "Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG"?

Just download the drivers of that Wireless-card [from Intel itself](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/wireless/pro2200bg).

(Specs of [Acer TravelMate 4001WLMi](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/acer-travelmate-4001wlmi-15/4507-3121_7-31496944.html)).

---

**Edit:**

If the installation of the Intel-driver doesn't work we need to know the hardware id of your Wireless card. Look in the Device Manager and in the Properties of the unidentified Wireless network controller.

We need to know the Hardware Ids:

[image]

---

**Edit #2:**

Because Intel doesn't support the "Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG" for Windows 7 anymore you could try the Vista drivers.

Goto [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15798&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%20Vista%2032*&DownloadType=Drivers) and download the first file. (`11.5.1.2_VT_DRIVERS.zip`)

Unzip `11.5.1.2_VT_DRIVERS.zip`

Goto the "Device Manager" and to the properties of the unidentified Wireless card. Choose <kbd>Update driver</kbd> and next "Browse my computer for driver software". Browse to the `v32` (for 32bit OS) or `v64` (for a 64bit OS) directory you unzipped. The driver should (hopefully) install correctly.

Comment: I don't know, how to check that?

Comment: Chances are you can just run the driver installation software and the install will tell you if it is compatible. As the specs on cnet.com says it is the "Intel PRO/Wireless 2200BG", chances are it is. If it is not the Intel install will tell you it can't find any compatible hardware and abort. You could check the Hardware Management in Windows what the ProductID is of the unidentified hardware-card. But first i would try this Intel install.

Comment: If the Intel install doesn't work i added the instruction to my answer to find out what the "Hardware Id" is of your card.

Comment: On this "Download Centre" page it says "Intel® PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection does not support Microsoft Windows* 7". Does it mean I have to get XP back?

Comment: Yes. It does say that (i see now). But [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/22201-intel-pro-wireless-2200bg-driver.html) some have had luck with the Vista (and even XP) driver. Just follow the instruction from leinadamil (download the driver/unzip and update driver and point to the vista 32bit folder).  (I take it you installed Win7 32bit and not 64?)

Comment: I added (Edit #2) some instruction to install the Vista drivers. Hopefully they will install correctly. Use the v32 for 32bit OS or v64 for 64bit OS.

Comment: It is 32bit, sorry, I forgot to mention.